# Representing null in JSON

Tags: json, null, jackson, gson

What is the preferred method for returning null values in JSON? Is there a different preference for primitives?

For example, if my object on the server has an Integer called "myCount" with no value, the most correct JSON for that value would be:

```json
{}
```

or

```json
{
    "myCount": null
}
```

or

```json
{
    "myCount": 0
}
```

Same question for Strings - if I have a null string "myString" on the server, is the best JSON:

```json
{}
```

or

```json
{
    "myString": null
}
```

or

```json
{
    "myString": ""
}
```

or (lord help me)

```json
{
    "myString": "null"
}
```

I like the convention for collections to be represented in the JSON as an empty collection http://jtechies.blogspot.nl/2012/07/item-43-return-empty-arrays-or.html

An empty Array would be represented:

```json
{
    "myArray": []
}
```

**EDIT Summary**

The 'personal preference' argument seems realistic, but short sighted in that, as a community we will be consuming an ever greater number of disparate services/sources. Conventions for JSON structure would help normalize consumption and reuse of said services. As far as establishing a standard, I would suggest adopting most of the Jackson conventions with a few exceptions:

- Objects are preferred over primitives.
- Empty collections are preferred over null.
- Objects with no value are represented as null.
- Primitives return their value.

If you are returning a JSON object with mostly null values, you may have a candidate for refactoring into multiple services.

```json
{
    "value1": null,
    "value2": null,
    "text1": null,
    "text2": "hello",
    "intValue": 0, //use primitive only if you are absolutely sure the answer is 0
    "myList": [],
    "myEmptyList": null, //NOT BEST PRACTICE - return [] instead
    "boolean1": null, //use primitive only if you are absolutely sure the answer is true/false
    "littleboolean": false
}
```

The above JSON was generated from the following Java class.

```java
package jackson;    
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;    
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
    
public class JacksonApp {    
    public static class Data {    
        public Integer value1;    
        public Integer value2;
        public String text1;
        public String text2 = "hello";
        public int intValue;
        public List<Object> myList = new ArrayList<Object>();
        public List<Object> myEmptyList;
        public Boolean boolean1;
        public boolean littleboolean;   
   }
    
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
       ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
       System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(new Data()));
   }
}
```

Maven dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: There is no best way. Pick what's easiest to consume for the client in your concrete use case. In the spirit of returning empty collections instead of `null`, consider if your client is better of with the empty string or `null` -- a string containing the word "null" is indistinguishable from a valid value, don't do that.

Comment: 0 or an empty string could very well have different meaning from null, which could have different meaning from the attribute not existing. If you want to represent null, use null. It's the most explicit.

Comment: In Objective-C there is a defined `NSNull` class which has a singleton instance.  A reference to that instance is equivalent to JSON's `null`.  I would guess that another language could do the same thing.  Of course, one would have to check the class of the received object before casting to the presumed class -- be "null aware", as it were.

Comment: Note that having a "null" list isn't best practice in Java either: if the list is expected to be empty, initialise it to an empty list.  If it is required to *remain* empty (e.g. because it will be replaced wholesale by a new list rather than modified to add values), initialise it to *the* empty list (i.e. `Collections.emptyList()`).  Doing so avoids null reference bugs that can be a pain otherwise.

Comment: @HotLicks - that's only possible because Objective-C is dynamically typed.  In Java, for instance, you couldn't have a (useful) `Null` class because you would only be able to assign its values to objects of its own type or of type `Object`.

Comment: @PeriataBreatta You're confusing "null pointers" with "null values". The former is bad, the latter is fine.

Answer (score 559, accepted):

Let's evaluate the parsing of each:

http://jsfiddle.net/brandonscript/Y2dGv/

```
var json1 = '{}';
var json2 = '{"myCount": null}';
var json3 = '{"myCount": 0}';
var json4 = '{"myString": ""}';
var json5 = '{"myString": "null"}';
var json6 = '{"myArray": []}';

console.log(JSON.parse(json1)); // {}
console.log(JSON.parse(json2)); // {myCount: null}
console.log(JSON.parse(json3)); // {myCount: 0}
console.log(JSON.parse(json4)); // {myString: ""}
console.log(JSON.parse(json5)); // {myString: "null"}
console.log(JSON.parse(json6)); // {myArray: []}
```

---

> ### The **tl;dr** here:
>
> The fragment in the *json2* variable is the way [the JSON spec](http://www.json.org/) indicates `null` should be represented. But as always, it depends on what you're doing -- sometimes the "right" way to do it doesn't always work for your situation. Use your judgement and make an informed decision.

---

**JSON1 `{}`**

This returns an empty object. There is no data there, and it's only going to tell you that whatever key you're looking for (be it `myCount` or something else) is of type `undefined`.

---

**JSON2 `{"myCount": null}`**

In this case, `myCount` is actually defined, albeit its value is `null`. This is *not* the same as both "not `undefined` and not `null`", and if you were testing for one condition or the other, this might succeed whereas JSON1 would fail.

This is the definitive way to represent `null` per [the JSON spec](http://www.json.org/).

---

**JSON3 `{"myCount": 0}`**

In this case, myCount is 0. That's not the same as `null`, and it's not the same as `false`. If your conditional statement evaluates `myCount > 0`, then this might be worthwhile to have. Moreover, if you're running calculations based on the value here, 0 could be useful. If you're trying to test for `null` however, this is actually not going to work at all.

---

**JSON4 `{"myString": ""}`**

In this case, you're getting an empty string. Again, as with JSON2, it's defined, but it's empty. You could test for `if (obj.myString == "")` but you could not test for `null` or `undefined`.

---

**JSON5 `{"myString": "null"}`**

This is probably going to get you in trouble, because you're setting the *string* value to null; in this case, `obj.myString == "null"` however it is *not* `== null`.

---

**JSON6 `{"myArray": []}`**

This will tell you that your array `myArray` exists, but it's empty. This is useful if you're trying to perform a count or evaluation on `myArray`. For instance, say you wanted to evaluate the number of photos a user posted - you could do `myArray.length` and it would return `0`: defined, but no photos posted.

Comment: Thanks a lot, very helpful.  

Just a small side node; when Play Json (scala) serializes Option[String] = None  result is `JSON1` i.e. `{}`

Comment: Is there no option for `{"myObject": {}}`? Is setting a value to an empty object possible?

Comment: Sure, go ahead. It means something different than null.

Answer (score 270):

`null` is not zero. It is not a value, *per se*: it is a value outside the domain of the variable indicating missing or unknown data.

There is only one way to represent `null` in JSON. Per the specs ([RFC 4627](http://www.rfc-editor.org/info/rfc4627) and [json.org](http://www.json.org/)):

> ```
> 2.1.  Values
>
> A JSON value MUST be an object, array, number, or string, or one of
> the following three literal names:
>
>   false null true
> ```

[image]

Comment: It is such a shame that null has to be present at all. 4 characters for nothing. It would have been nice to simply exclude the value entirely.

`json = '{"myValue":}';`

Comment: @Richard A Quadling - 

I'm a follower of Hal Abelson's "Programs must be written for people to read, and only incidentally for machines to execute". I'd prefer the word 'null', confirming the programmer's intention, and not just a question of accidental omission.

Comment: @ScottSmith: Of course programs must be written for people to read.  But JSON values are not programs, they are data.  Programming languages have positional parameters where the person doesn't type `null` for every unspecified function parameter.  And under the hood, it would be nice if the serialization of a function call didn't have to send 4 ASCII characters 'n', 'u', 'l', 'l' for every parameter that the person omits, quite readably, by typing nothing between two commas.

Comment: @Dave May: "JSON values are not programs" -- My point is about signaling intent in an unambiguous way. Yes, it costs an extra four characters, and for some applications the difference may be significant. In many cases though, the benefits of making errors *look wrong* far outweighs the benefits of minor optimizations.

Comment: @Dave Also, according to json.org, JSON "is easy for humans to read and write."

Comment: @RichardAQuadling Although on the one hand I agree (because I'm a sucker for shorthand), you can also let JSON values be empty strings, so that wouldn't work. The other option, completely omitting anything, like `"first":true, "second":, "third":false` could easily be confusing or mistaken for an error.

Comment: It says "Easy for humans to read and write", but then proceeds to define the Unicode escaping rules, wiping out that prior claim.

Comment: Also note that if you have problems with 4 ASCII characters, JSON isn't the best approach, look at [Binary JSON](http://bsonspec.org/) or better to a pure binary format.

Answer (score 49):

There is only one way to represent `null`; that is with `null`.

```
console.log(null === null);   // true
console.log(null === true);   // false
console.log(null === false);  // false
console.log(null === 'null'); // false
console.log(null === "null"); // false
console.log(null === "");     // false
console.log(null === []);     // false
console.log(null === 0);      // false
```

That is to say; if any of the clients that consume your JSON representation use the `===` operator; it could be a problem for them.

## no value

If you want to convey that you have an object whose attribute `myCount` has no value:

```
{ "myCount": null }
```

## no attribute / missing attribute

What if you to convey that you have an object with no attributes:

```
{}
```

Client code will try to access `myCount` and get `undefined`; it's not there.

## empty collection

What if you to convey that you have an object with an attribute `myCount` that is an empty list:

```
{ "myCount": [] }
```

Comment: +1 good examples with comparisons, but it would be helpful to distinguish between javascript and json, meaning, representation of null in javascript didn't have to match the json's (although it does).

Answer (score 18):

I would use `null` to show that there is no value for that particular key.  For example, use `null` to represent that "number of devices in your household connects to internet" is unknown.

On the other hand, use `{}` if that particular key is not applicable.  For example, you should not show a count, even if `null`, to the question "number of cars that has active internet connection" is asked to someone who does not own any cars.

I would avoid defaulting any value unless that default makes sense.  While you may decide to use `null` to represent no value, certainly never use `"null"` to do so.

Answer (score 9):

I would pick "default" for data type of variable (`null` for strings/objects, `0` for numbers), but indeed check what code that will consume the object expects. Don't forget there there is sometimes distinction between `null`/default vs. "not present".

Check out [null object pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) - sometimes it is better to pass some special object instead of `null` (i.e. `[]` array instead of `null` for arrays or `""` for strings).

Answer (score 4):

According to the [JSON spec](https://www.json.org/), the outermost container does not have to be a dictionary (or 'object') as implied in most of the comments above. It can also be a list or a bare value (i.e. string, number, boolean or null). If you want to represent a null value in JSON, the entire JSON string (excluding the quotes containing the JSON string) is simply `null`. No braces, no brackets, no quotes. You could specify a dictionary containing a key with a null value (`{"key1":null}`), or a list with a null value (`[null]`), but these are not null values themselves - they are proper dictionaries and lists. Similarly, an empty dictionary (`{}`) or an empty list (`[]`) are perfectly fine, but aren't null either.

In Python:

```
>>> print json.loads('{"key1":null}')
{u'key1': None}
>>> print json.loads('[null]')
[None]
>>> print json.loads('[]')
[]
>>> print json.loads('{}')
{}
>>> print json.loads('null')
None
```

Comment: Note it is the McKeeman Form grammar on the right sidebar of the linked JSON spec page that validates the assertion that bare `null` constitutes valid JSON. The main body text and illustrations there are ambiguous and if anything seem to suggest only objects and arrays are valid at the root.

Answer (score 2):

This is a personal and situational choice. The important thing to remember is that the empty string and the number zero are conceptually distinct from `null`.

In the case of a `count` you probably always want some valid number (unless the `count` is unknown or undefined), but in the case of strings, who knows? The empty string could *mean* something in your application. Or maybe it doesn't. That's up to you to decide.

Answer (score 1):

## 'null' is best for practical use

FWIW, using PHP as an example, PHP interprets empty sets as entries made by PHP...

```php
// This loop will iterate one item with the value 'the car'
$empty_json = '["the car"]';
$some_json_array = json_decode($empty_json);

foreach ($some_json_array as $i) {
  echo "PHP sees one item";
}
```

output: `PHP sees the car`

```php
// This loop will iterate one item, but with no values
$empty_json = '[""]';
$some_json_array = json_decode($empty_json);

foreach ($some_json_array as $i) {
  echo "PHP sees: $i";
}
```

output: `PHP sees`

```php
// This loop will iterate nothing because PHP's `json_decode()` function knew it was `null`
$empty_json = 'null';
$some_json_array = json_decode($empty_json);

foreach ($some_json_array as $i) {
  echo "PHP sees one item";
}
```

output: (nothing, `foreach` will not loop)

Comment: This Question is not restricted to `java` or `phython`, though it has a Java example in the Question and a Python example in another Answer. This Answer shows some from PHP to round out the area covered by the Answers.