# Default behavior for a JSON Serializer if it is passed null?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I have an ISerializer interface with several different implementations and a simple contract:

```
string Serialize<T>(T data);
T Deserialize<T>(string serializedData);
```

One of the implementations is a JSON serializer. I'm debating how it should behave if the value passed into either of these methods is null. Should it return null? Or empty string? I realize this is a design decision, I'm curious how others have handled it and what kind of gotchas or design considerations that should factor into my decision? Thanks.

Comment: related if not duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21120999/representing-null-in-json

Comment: @Habib No it's not a duplicate. I'm not asking how to handle a PROPERTY that is null when converting to/from JSON, I'm asking what to do when the whole object is null

Answer (score 0):

If an object is null, then it should be serialized to JSON `null` and deserialized to C# `null` (and the reverse).

You're going to run into a problem though if T is a non-nullable type (e.g. `int` or `Timespan`). I'm not sure what to do there - usually the behavior (e.g. in json.net) is to return a zero value - for example, trying to deserialize null to int returns an int 0.