# JSON.parse allows null as value

Tags: javascript, json

I am passing null to [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) and although the first parameter is documented saying that it should be a string value, it still works to supply `null`.

How come this does not throw an error even though even though the documentation state this is for strings and can this be safely and reliable used in multiple browsers?

Comment: check the below answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21120999/representing-null-in-json

Comment: I feel like that question is different since it talks about using `null` within JSON objects. JSON objects that `JSON.stringify` has gone over resulting in strings. I simply throw `null` into my `JSON.parse()` directly.

Comment: I assume `parse` might internally cast the given value to a string, which would be `"null"`, which is a valid JSON value.

Comment: Ok if that is the case I wonder how reliable this is `cross-browser`.

Comment: JSON.parse("null") or JSON.parse(null) both of them are casted as "null" which is a valid json, but if you pass JSON.parse('') it will throw an exception it's an empty string

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [ECMAScript spec](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-json-object) says as the first step for `JSON.parse`:

> 1. Let `JText` be `ToString(text)`.

Meaning it'll cast whatever argument it's given to a string, and `null` casts to `"null"`, which is the valid JSON representation of `null`.

Note that a single such JSON primitive *shouldn't* be valid, a JSON string should be wrapped in an object or array. But parsers have traditionally been lax with that, partially due to it making the implementation simpler I suppose.

Comment: So I guess the most reliable thing to do here is check the input value to be a string before handing it over to `JSON.parse` since I am abusing it otherwise?

Comment: "a JSON string should be wrapped in an object or array" — The original JSON specification said that, but not very clearly. [rfc7159](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7159) updates it to say: A JSON text is a serialized value.  Note that certain previous
   specifications of JSON constrained a JSON text to be an object or an array.

Comment: @Quentin A case of the spec trailing the implementation, I suppose?

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised.

Comment: @Stephan I would say you should *know* what values you're working with to begin with. If you have a `null` value where you should have a string, something's wrong in your code. More broadly you might want to `try..catch` any and all `JSON.parse` calls if you expect your JSON may be invalid in any way.

Comment: Well I know for certain the value is always a `string` or a `null` that I am supplying. Since `JSON.parse` accepts both they are not really invalid. I guess it is not 'proper' to hand it over a null value though.

Comment: @Stephan A `null` value basically means "no value", in which case your code indeed shouldn't even go into the branch where it tries to parse "no value" as JSON but instead go do something else.

Comment: True. Thanks for helping out.

Comment: intersingly the node.js JSON allows a Buffer to be parsed, presumably because the default toString for a buffer is utf8, which, assuming the buffer contains valid JSON, works. this means JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./package.json')) works fine.

Answer (score 1):

See [the specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-json.parse):

> 1. Let JText be ToString(text).

It doesn't require that the first argument be a string, it attempts to convert it to a string.

`"" + null` will give you `"null"` which is a string containing valid JSON.

This is [also in the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-tostring):

> Null: Return "null".