# Errors in TypeScript vs. Try/Catch

Tags: typescript

**How should I use *Try/Catch* in TypeScript?** I don't want it to check for any errors in a given block because I already check for them (the error is expected and the state is controlled by the catch).

I have the code wrapped in *Try/Catch* (just example):

```
try {
    let data = localStorage.getItem('something');
    // Err. TS2345; I know, that's why you're in the try block
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    // Err. TS2531; I know, that's why you're in the try block
    data.exp = new Date(data.exp * 1000);
    return data;
} catch {
    return null;
}
```

TypeScript refuses to compile it. Is there any way I can tell TypeScript that I know about the error and I'm okay with it? I don't want to use `//@ts-ignore` on every line (assuming I can have a longer code) and I don't want to turn off *strict mode*. Is there any better solution?

Comment: `catch (_e) { return null; }`. You can't just write `catch {  }`

Comment: @Nick - Just `} catch {` is valid now, but I don't think that's what they're asking about. I think the issue is the things a bit hidden in the code comments.

Comment: I want TypeScript to ignore errors in **try** block (because thats why it is in try block) and **empty catch is valid** but thank you.

Comment: These are typescript errors and not runtime errors. TS errors are not related to runtime and code executions error. Try/Catch are for runtime errors, so use `ts-ignore` to ignore them.

Comment: @NaorLevi I know it is not runtime.

Comment: Write it in a more type-safe way, e.g. https://tsplay.dev/N9pVjw.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Out of curiosity, why doesn't the first param of `JSON.parse` accept `null` in addition to a string (or as an overload)? V8 is happy to accept it and return `null`.

Comment: @jsejcksn I don't know, you'd have to ask the maintainers of the lib types where it's defined: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/0f3d0e047014ca71f0b8b457aa83cc8590bc5650/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1052-L1074

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thank you. I got it but this is just an example. Sometimes you want to try/catch something and you are expecting an error.

Comment: @jsejcksn indeed it looks like people already have: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43232

Comment: @jonrsharpe I should have done a bit more research first (the spec specifies a string): https://stackoverflow.com/a/46464692/438273

Comment: @Jax-p but if what you're expecting is a type-related error the compiler can already tell you about, you probably shouldn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TypeScript's purpose is to help you with coding errors caused by type issues. It's giving you TS2345 because you're passing `string | null` into `JSON.parse` (which expects just `string`), and it's giving you TS2531 and TS2339 because your code is using `data` as though it won't be `null` (but it may well be) and as though it has an `exp` property (which as far as TypeScript knows, it doesn't).

If you want to disable type checking for `data`, use [the `any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any):

```typescript
try {
    let data: any = localStorage.getItem('something');
//          ^^^^^−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−− here
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    data.exp = new Date(data.exp * 1000);
    return data;
} catch {
    return null;
}
```

From the linked documentation:

> **`any`**
>
> TypeScript also has a special type, `any`, that you can use whenever you don’t want a particular value to cause typechecking errors.

Comment: I understand the errors and TypeScript, but I want to control the application by using errors and catching them. So the only option is to re-type it to **any**? I don't like that, but it's better than ts-ignore. Thank you.