# Is there a standard way to indicate an invalid value in an ISO8601-formatted timestamp?

Tags: datetime, timestamp, iso8601

I have some code that creates an ISO8601-formatted timestamp but if the incoming date is in an invalid format, the conversion fails.

I'd like to know if there's a standard way of representing an invalid timestamp in this format?

Wikipedia mentions years prior to 1583 as not being handled under normal operation so my first thought was to simply set the value to something like `0000-01-01T00:00:00Z`. If there's a more standard way to indicate an invalid value though, I'd rather use it instead.

Comment: And which programming language do you want to use?

Comment: If there's a standard way of representing it, wouldn't that make it a valid timestamp?

Comment: C++ is what I'm using but it was more the general approach I was interested in rather than the specifics of a particular language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ISO 8601 does not define a string that represents an invalid timestamp.  It only defines what a *valid* formatted string looks like.

Also, ISO 8601 uses a [*proleptic* Gregorian calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proleptic_Gregorian_calendar), which means that all positive years are valid.  It allows for negative years (by agreement), but does not define eras such as BC/BCE.  In other words, one day before `0001-01-01` would be `0000-12-31` in the proleptic Gregorian calendar.  One day before `0000-01-01` would be `-0001-12-31` (and year 0 is a leap year).

As far as how you represent "invalid" in *your* code, that's entirely language and implementation dependent.  In many cases, a `null` would be appropriate.  If you are strictly working with strings, then perhaps `""` would be better.  Hard to say without more context.

Comment: The data is being exchanged as a JSON string so an empty string sounds like a sensible approach to me.

Comment: `null` (not as a string) is also valid in JSON.  Depending on what it's being deserialized into, it may be more appropriate.  For example, as a .Net developer, I might deserialize that field into a `Nullable<DateTime>` (aka. `DateTime?`), in which case the null would automatically come through, but an empty string would be a case I'd have to go out of my way teach the parser how to handle.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21121267/634824) may also be useful in your decision making.

Comment: That looks great.