# save and load nullable strings in JSON files

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

for my Unity game I created a JSON file that holds the speedrun times. The saved times are Timespan strings. When loading the data I parse the strings to Timespan values. When saving the time I save the Timespan as a string to the file.

Example level in the JSON file:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "personalBest": "00:00:00.0001336",
  "perfectTime": "00:00:00.0001335",
}
```

If a level is not passed yet I want the personalBest property having the value `null` instead of something like this

**00:00:00.0000000**

or

**99:99:99.9999999**

In my serializable class I currently have this code

```
[Serializable]
public class Level
{
    public int id;
    public string? personalBest; // this value could be null
    public string perfectTime;
}
```

But I get this error

> **CS0453** The type 'string' must be a non-nullable type in order to use
>   it as parameter T in the generic type or method 'System.Nullable'

Is a workaround possible?

Comment: you should take a look at brandonscript answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21121267/2748412) it explains alot.

Comment: should this question get closed?

Comment: yes, it is a duplicate. As a note, you should maybe rethink the way you save things, you can avoid having this saved as null by making `personalBest` getting the value from an external list containing the id and time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So in C# `string` is already a nullable type. You should be fine just using a normal `string` in place of `string?`. This means you can just set it to null by doing the following:

```
string myString = null;
```

If I'm completely misunderstanding your question, please let me know.

For saving null in JSON, [check here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21121267/2748412)

Answer (score 1):

An important thing to understand regarding the `string` type is this:

> `string` is a reference type, thus nullable, and when a `string` field
>   is declared but not initialized it will have its value set to `""` and
>   not `null`.

I.e.:

```cs
public string myString;
if (myString != null) {
    Debug.Log("String is not null");
}
```

will print `String is not null` in the console.

This is what throws some people off, since usually reference types when declared but not yet initialized have their value set to `null` by default.

However, if you declare the variable with an autoproperty instead of a field, then it will behave as any other reference type, i.e. `null` by default.

```cs
public string myString {get;set;}
if (myString == null) {
    Debug.Log("String is null");
}
```

will print `String is null` in the console.