# how to write junit for the following code

Tags: spring-boot, junit, mockito

how to write test case for if else coditions.I am not getting coverage in the else block when giving the object as null.
Also not getting coverage in the catch block.

```
if (Object!= null) {
            if (Object.getId() != null) {
                responseModel = registrationService.updateVendor(Object);
            } else {
                responseModel = registrationService.save(Object);
            }
        } else {
            responseModel = new ResponseModel();
            responseModel.setCode(ERROR_1002);
            responseModel.setMessage(ERROR_MSG1002);
            logger.info("Vendor details not found");
        }

    } catch (NullPointerException  e) {
        //e.printStackTrace();

        responseModel = new ResponseModel();
        responseModel.setCode(ERROR_1000);
        responseModel.setMessage(ERROR_MSG1000);
        logger.error("Exception inside RegistrationController.Registration()" + e);

    }
```

Comment: could you share your test case code

Comment: @Test
 public void testCreateOrderNotNull() throws Exception {
  
 String json="{  \r\n" + "   \"Id\": \"1\",\r\n" +
    
    "         \"swiftCode\":\"asdsdE988989\"\r\n" + 
    "      }\r\n" + 
    "   ]\r\n" + 
    "}\r\n" + 
  MockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("registration").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .content(json)).andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk());
 }

Comment: I am assuming your string `json` will get converted to some DTO object at server end. You should try to send a null represent of object.

Comment: @Test(expected=NullPointerException.class)
 public void testCreateOrderVendorDetailsNull() throws Exception {
  String json=null;
  mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/registration").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .content(json)).andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.message", Matchers.is("r Details not found")));
  } this test case fails

Comment: follow this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21120999/representing-null-in-json

Comment: did it worked??

Comment: no.It didnt worked.

Comment: see in your how `Object` is getting populated. Is it getting resolved from the JSON string we are passing ?