# How to parse "{}" empty value (into String)

Tags: java, json, jackson, fasterxml

Given json:

```
{
  "name" : {}
}
```

I would like to parse it into the following Java object using `com.fasterxml.jackson`:

```
class MyClass {
  private String name;
}
```

If you try it, you will get:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.String` out of START_OBJECT token
```

**Is there any way to configure the jackson deserializer (globally for best) it can handle these `empty objects` as `nulls` without changing the attribute type (from String)?**

Comment: Your json shouldn't be { "name" : null } ? We don't represend null object with {} in json.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21120999/representing-null-in-json

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/1885) they mention it doesn't support parsing empty objects. One idea from the thread is to just *`replace("{}", "null")` on the JSON string before parsing* which is **not** pretty, but might work.

Comment: Should be, but that JSON is not mine. And what I have understood, it is still valid with `{}`, right?

Comment: Well, you should always be able to use a custom deserializer to convert empty objects to strings. However, using different types for empty and non-empty values is a receipe for catastrophe, better use `"name":null` as the others suggested - or maybe `"name":""`. Having to check the type is bound to bite you in the a** eventually.

Comment: @angel What does the `name` contain if it is not empty? `{}` would make sense if the name consists of multiple parts (like `{firstname: .., lastname:..}`. But in that case you should not deserialize it to a string, but to an object that contains those properties. If it only contains a string but `{}` when it is empty, then it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Right guys, I understand that `name: {}` for `String` is bad. But as I have stated, I'm not producing this kind of messy JSON :-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do that you can write your own deserializer. Following [this](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization) you extend the StdDeserializer and register it in the class.

---

**Author edit:**

I have used following deserializer for strings and it's working fine, thanks:

```
public class EmptyObjectDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<String> {

    public EmptyObjectDeserializer() {
        this(null);
    }

    public EmptyObjectDeserializer(Class<?> vc) {
        super(vc);
    }

    @Override
    public String deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        JsonNode node = jp.getCodec().readTree(jp);
        return node.asText("");
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't help at all. This doesn't describes what the problem is and the correct solution for it.

Comment: Will try it for `String.class`. Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: this may pass as a comment, not as an answer.

Comment: I have edited the answer to include my custom deserializer for string. That solution is working well and is best among the options what I have found. Edit is waiting for review.

Comment: A bit overkill, it could be simplier, no need for a deserializer, just add a class for Name

Comment: @JulienRevaultd'A... I don't agree. Why you would want custom class into your model class when there should be a string. And when that model is made up of dozens of attributes and nested class, you really don't want substitute every string into custom class. One serializer is imho much better.

Comment: Just because in JSON as soon as you have a {} it is not a string but an object. And it works perfectly with an object

Answer (score 0):

In json, `{}` is an `Object`, meaning it can have fields (like a POJO in Java). As you are trying to deserialise it into a `String`, it is throwing an Exception (Imagine trying to assign a POJO to a String reference in Java).

In this case, there are two options:

- Configure your class not to include empty fields. This can be done via annotation or configuration on your `ObjectMapper` instance, e.g.:

  ```
  @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
  class MyClass {
    private String name;
  }
  ```

  OR

  `mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_EMPTY);`

  This option might not work if the response has not null `name` in it. If it's an object with not null value, Jackson will try to deserialise it into a `String` and fail.
- Change the type of `name` to `Object` (or rather, a POJO with all the elements response can contain). This would however mean you need to change the code that accesses `name` element as it will no longer be `String`.

Comment: First suggestion with `@JsonInclude` is only for the serialization - that's not what I'm asking. Second suggestion is something I have in mind but would not like to do. THanks

Comment: If your request contains fields under `name` object then you have no other option but to change the type of  `name` field if you want to deserialise the response content.

Answer (score 0):

No need to write your own deserializer, you just have to encapsulate your name object in a class and it works :

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
        "name"
})
public class JsonExample {
        @JsonProperty("name")
        public Name name;
}
```

and

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
        "first",
        "last"
})
public class Name {
    @JsonProperty("first")
    public String first_name;
    @JsonProperty("last")
    public String last_name;
}
```

first name and last name are here as an example... don't know what's inside your Name object
so you can use your mapper :

```
JsonExample obj = mapper.readValue(file, JsonExample.class);
```