# How to replace undefined with null or treat it as false in javascript?

Tags: javascript

So I'm having this little generator, the info that get displayed should correspond to what values are populated on the database, the example below is a physical address

```
this.setState({
   companyEmail: json.data.companyEmail,
   company: json.data.company,
   line1: json.data.line1,
   line2: json.data.line2,
   city: json.data.city,
   ... 
});
```

So I could initialize those values with `null`, `undefined` or `""` it does not matter, on the fetch request the typeof those empty values turn to undefined.

Firebase don't like that, for me it cause no issue, I could hide the element  by checking if it's true or false like so

```
{line1 && <span>{line1}<br /></span>}
{line2 && <span>{line2}<br /></span>}
```

Well I mean it works until I tried updating the database, I got this error

> Error: Reference.set failed: First argument contains undefined in
>   property 'master.business.info.line2'

What I want to do is kindof turning undefined to null, because when sending null remove the child from the db, it's treated like a real value.

On the server side, it's regular db update

```
master.update({
   company: company,
   line1: line1,
   line2: line2,
   city: city,
   ... 
})
.then(() => {
   response.sendStatus(200);
}).catch(function (err) {
   console.log(err);
   response.sendStatus(204);
});
```

I could use if statement and setState accordingly but that's too much work. I need to make to fetch request because I need those values, it's a form to edit info.

Also using empty strings like `""` is not good, it gets display inside span, paragraph or whatever.

This is not a duplicate, on react.js my goal is to not setState for undefined values and keep the init values on the constructor.

Comment: You wan't that key to be there or you want to remove key itself from object ? i.e if line2 is undefined you want it on object passed to update on or not ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Representing null in JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21120999/representing-null-in-json)

Comment: so `company: company || null,` doesn't work?

Comment: It's a form, on mount value it's set to undefined because of the fetch request, on change it turns to string, I want to get rid of undefined to turn it into null that way, if you update line1 and keep line2 as is, you wouldn't mess with db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe if you change your setState like this:

```js
const {companyEmail, company, line1, line2, city} = json.data;
this.setState({
   companyEmail,
   company,
   line1,
   line2,
   city,
   ... 
});
```

If any var doesn't have value, it doesn't add to state.

Here, you could check before update. Try something like this:

```js
const objUpdate = {
   company: company,
   line1: line1,
   line2: line2,
   city: city,
   ... 
};
const cloneObjUpdate = {...objUpdate};
Object.keys(objUpdate).forEach(key=>{
    if(!Boolean(cloneObjUpdate[key])) delete cloneObjUpdate[key];
});

master.update(cloneObjUpdate);
```

For keep object with `null` values, just remove `delete` and set a `null` value:

```js
const objUpdate = {
   company: company,
   line1: line1,
   line2: line2,
   city: city,
   ... 
};
const cloneObjUpdate = {...objUpdate};
Object.keys(objUpdate).forEach(key=>{
    if(!Boolean(cloneObjUpdate[key])) cloneObjUpdate[key] = null;
});
```

Comment: Well I have to try that, for me it looks there's no difference, you just make it compact. Sorry it's not working, still getting undefined as typeof

Comment: I'm sorry, check my answer again... I've made a update

Comment: Do you know how can I keep those values but set them to null? I am running into some issues when editing the db with empty strings like line2: '', your function remove the child from the obj and the db dont get updated because the obj does not contain that value:null

Answer (score 0):

I started with changing `undefined` to `null` for Firebase’s sake, but then I realized it was easier to just remove the `undefined` keys altogether:

```
const removeUndefinedKeys = (collection) => Object.keys(collection).reduce((result, key) => (
  ![undefined, null].includes(collection[key])
    ? { ...result, [key]: collection[key] }
    : result
), {})
```

Comment: Be careful though, as missing fields are not indexed and won't show up in queries on a given field.