# '' in JSON_OBJECT value

Tags: sql, json, oracle

I am trying to achieve the '' in varchar field instead of NULL if value is not present in the column.

```
SELECT JSON_OBJECT('name' VALUE 'nikhil') FROM DUAL

{'name' : 'nikhil'}

SELECT JSON_OBJECT('name' VALUE null) FROM DUAL
{'name': ''}
```

Comment: can you show what exactly do you expect as output ?

Comment: SELECT JSON_OBJECT('name' VALUE (SELECT COL1 FROM TEMP1)) FROM DUAL so in this query if i col1 has value then i got the value if data is not present then i got null but i got '' for name key.

Comment: check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21120999/representing-null-in-json. Oracle gives you the option to return the value null or to not show the element (JSON_on_null_clause in the docs).