# Remove items from a dictionary if condition is met

Tags: dictionary, ansible, key-value

I have a dictionary `dict1` from which I want to remove all items where `b` is null, that means not just the property `b`, but the whole dictionary.

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    dict1: [{a:1,b:2,c:3},{a:1,b:"null",c:3},{a:1,b:2,c:3}]

  tasks: 
  - set_fact:
      dict2: "{{item | reject(item.b, 'eq', 'null')}}"
    loop: "{{dict1}}"
```

The output should look like this:

```yaml
dict2: [{a:1,b:2,c:3},{a:1,b:2,c:3}]
```

Note: there can be N items in the dictionary and/or N key-value pairs in the same dictionary. Also, there can be N number of `b`'s in the dictionary that have null values, so it has to remove of all them.

Comment: _Also, there can be n number of b's in dict_ > that does not matter, actually because a dictionary cannot have the same key multiple times, so the last definition of `b` will override other previous definition of its values.

Comment: Also not that `b:"null"` is not a real `null`, it is just the string `'null'`, if you want a JSON `null`, you should do: [`b: null`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21120999/representing-null-in-json).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`selectattr`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#jinja-filters.selectattr) filter to filter a list of dictionaries.

Given the task:

```yaml
- debug:
    var: dict1 | selectattr('b', '!=', 'null')
```

This would yield:

```yaml
dict1 | selectattr('b', '!=', 'null'):
  - a: 1
    b: 2
    c: 3
  - a: 1
    b: 2
    c: 3
```

Answer (score 2):

Given the dictionary with `null` value instead of the string `"null"`

```yaml
dict1:
  - {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
  - {a: 1, b: null, c: 3}
  - {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
```

Use [selectattr](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#jinja-filters.selectattr) without a test

```yaml
    - debug:
        var: dict1|selectattr('b')
```

gives

```yaml
dict1|selectattr('b'):
  - {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
  - {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
```

[Quoting](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#jinja-filters.selectattr):

> If no test is specified, the attribute’s value will be evaluated as a boolean.

Answer (score 1):

A solution with a simple loop and test:

```
- name: "tips2"
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    dict1: [{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}, {"a": 1, "b": "null", "c": 3},{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}]

  tasks: 
    - set_fact:
        dict2: "{{dict2 | default([]) +  [item] }}"
      loop: "{{dict1}}"
      when: item.b != "null"

    - name: debug users      
      debug:
        msg: "{{dict2}}"
```

result:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "a": 1,
            "b": 2,
            "c": 3
        },
        {
            "a": 1,
            "b": 2,
            "c": 3
        }
    ]
}
```