# null check is always evaluating to false

Tags: java, json, null, gson, jsonobjectrequest

```
import org.json.JSONObject;

String someStringJsonData = "{\"someKey\": " + "null" + "}"; 
JSONObject someJsonObjectData = new JSONObject(someStringJsonData); 
Object someKey = someJsonObjectData.get("someKey");  
if (null == someKey) {                 
        System.out.println("someKey is null");                             
}
```

I have the above simple snippet of code. I would expect to see "someKey is null" printed, however, my code never goes in the if loop. I tried printing value of someKey and it shows to be null. Not sure what I am missing.

I tried different values of the jsonString from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21120999/representing-null-in-json) but to no avail.

Comment: Which `JSONObject` are you actually using? gson does not have a class called `JSONObject`, only [`JsonObject`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/JsonObject.html).

Comment: I am using->  import org.json.JSONObject;

Comment: The [documentation of `JSONObject::get`](https://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/org/json/JSONObject.html#get-java.lang.String-) states that this method does throw an exception when the key is not found.

Comment: The link to the post does not link to a post.

Comment: Here the key is there but the value for it is null. It does throw a JSONException if I was doing `someJsonObjectData.get("someOtherKey");  `

Comment: Seems like a natural troubleshooting step would be to check what non-null value is in fact retrieved.  Probably it is `JSONObject.NULL` as opposed to a Java `null`.

Comment: What does `System.out.println(someKey.getClass());` print?

Comment: Please [edit] the post and add a [MRE]. Looking at the [relevant source code of `JSONObject`](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java/blob/master/src/main/java/org/json/JSONObject.java#L564), it should throw an exception, even if the key is present, but the value associated is `null`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to do the check for

`JSONObject.NULL` and not `null`
https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#NULL.

Printing the class of someKey helped. Thank you everyone for your time!!

Answer (score 1):

Per [its docs](https://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/org/json/JSONObject.html), the internal form of the value of a `JSONObject` can contain values of these types: `Boolean`, `JSONArray`, `JSONObject`, `Number`, `String`, **or the `JSONObject.NULL` object**.  Therefore, I would not expect its `get()` method to return `null` for any key.  In your particular case, I would expect `someJsonObjectData.get("someKey")` to return `JSONObject.NULL`, which will compare unequal to `null`.

`JSONObject.NULL` is a specific object, so it should be safe to perform `==` comparisons with it:

```
import org.json.JSONObject;

// ...

    void doSomething() {
        String someStringJsonData = "{\"someKey\": null}"; 
        JSONObject someJsonObjectData = new JSONObject(someStringJsonData); 
        Object someValue = someJsonObjectData.get("someKey");  

        if (someValue == JSONObject.NULL) {                 
            System.out.println("someKey's value is null");                             
        }
    }
```