# How to handle JSON responses in Unity when part of the object could be NULL?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I receive two JSON responses from a server: one when a session is unavailable and another when it is available. The JSON responses are as follows:

```
// Unavailable 
{
    "data": {
        "session":null
    }
}

// Available
{
    "data": {
        "session":{
            "token": "12345",
            "name": "Jake"
    }
}
```

How can I handle these responses in Unity?

**Additional information:**

- I have created a `Session` class with the following properties: `token` and `name`.
- I am using JsonUtility to deserialize the JSON responses.
- I have create a class `ResponseData` that wraps the Session into the `data` property

**Attempted solutions**
I've tried to handle the possible null Session in many different ways but they just don't compile since I'm trying to compare null with an object...

**// Solution 1**

```
ResponseData responseData = JsonUtility.FromJson<ResponseData>(jsonText);

// I receive this error 
// "operator == cannot be applied to operand of type "ResponseData" and null"
// Check if session is available
if (responseData.session == null)
{
    Debug.Log("Session is not available.");
}
else
{....
```

**// Solution 2**

```
ResponseData responseData = JsonUtility.FromJson<ResponseData>(jsonText);

// Check if session is available
if (responseData.session is null)
{
    Debug.Log("Session is not available.");
}
else
{....
```

**// Solution 3**

```
 if (Response.session.Equals(default(ResponseData)))
```

This one actually works, but I'm wondering if this is the right way to handle a case like the one explained above.

Any idea? it sounds like a very common scenario but I can't find a correct solution to manage it.

Comment: Depending on your version of C# I believe you can set your Session in `ResponseData` to be nullable by adding `?` after your type declaration

Comment: _"they just don't compile since I'm trying to compare null with an object..."_ Are you sure? This looks legit. What error are you actually getting?

Comment: All 3 seem like they should work. Show your types. Do you have structs in there somewhere?

Comment: Please show the `ResponseData` and `Session` classes and the compile error.

Comment: Please show your code as a [mcve]

Comment: Hmm. This looks like it would work. If you send the compiler error and the `ResponseData` class I'm sure that would help us figure it out. 
Regardless, here's a link that may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21120999/representing-null-in-json

Comment: @phuzi I receive errors like "operator == cannot be applied to operand of type "ResponseData" and null"

Comment: @WillLacey I've just updated the question with the error I receive

(operator == cannot be applied to operand of type "ResponseData" and null)

Comment: Sounds like `responseData.session` is not a nullable type. Can you include the definition of `ResponseData` type as well as whatever type the `session` property is?