Rreadng NULL/EMPTY from JSON in an HTTP post request handler
I'm posting data from excel to a back-end Python server. The JSON from excel VBA, just before sending is shown below: What you'll notice in  below. Is there is an empty cell/field after 2020-01-10?
[
    [
        "name",
        "RTX",
        "SPX",
        "NDX"
    ],
    [
        "date",
        "close",
        "close",
        "close"
    ],
    [
        "2020-01-10T05:00:00.000Z", ,
        200.1,
        300.1
    ],
    [
        "2020-01-11T05:00:00.000Z",
        100.1,
        200.2,
        300.2
    ]
]

The code in vba looks like this:
Set http = CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP")
With http
    .Open "POST", url, False
    .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
    .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    .setTimeouts ONE_MIN_MS, 5 * ONE_MIN_MS, ONE_MIN_MS, 5 * ONE_MIN_MS
    .send to_json
    Log "response status: " & .Status
    resp = .responseText
End With

When received by the Python Flask web application, I do the following:
data =  req.get_json()

This produces an error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/werkzeug/wrappers/request.py", line 620, in get_json
    rv = self.on_json_loading_failed(e)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/wrappers.py", line 131, in on_json_loading_failed
    return super().on_json_loading_failed(e)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/werkzeug/wrappers/request.py", line 645, in on_json_loading_failed
    raise BadRequest(f"Failed to decode JSON object: {e}")
werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequest: 400 Bad Request: Failed to decode JSON object: Expecting value: line 1 column 90 (char 89)

If I call req.get_data(), the bytes look like this:
b'[["name","RTX","SPX","NDX"],["date","close","close","close"],["2020-01-10T05:00:00.000Z",,200.1,300.1],["2020-01-11T05:00:00.000Z",100.1,200.2,300.2]]'

I have also tried using jsonify and JSON libraries to convert the above to a JSON, but they all fail.
I'm guessing it is because there is an empty value there that is not confirming to JSON standards maybe. Any solution to this on the Python side? Or, do I need to fill that sell with some value?

["2020-01-10T05:00:00.000Z",,200.1,300.1] is not valid json.  There needs to be something between those two commas.

You've not shown us how you create that json - that seems to be where the problem is.

it seems if i replace with null from the client it works. i didnt think null was valid either

Nulls in JSON - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21120999/representing-null-in-json
